# WebAIM Contrast Checker reports errors, but manual WAVE contrast checks pass just fine

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I ran one of my websites through the WebAIM Contrast Checker and was surprised to find that I received 17 Contrast Errors indicating that there is not enough color contrast between the text and the background. But if I sample the darkest areas that appear in the image behind the text and manually input those values into the WAVE Contrast Checker along with the text color, the contrast test passes just fine. I don't get it.

Here's a link to the Contrast Checker showing the results of my test:
https://wave.webaim.org/report#/usalearns.org

And here's a screen grab of the WAVE Contrast Checker results of manually inputting the darkest color that appears behind the text along with the text color.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

> Contrast is not tested when background gradients, transparency, etc. are present. **A CSS background color that provides sufficient contrast must be defined when a background image is in place.** This provides fall-back contrast in case images or CSS do not display.

It says this at the bottom of the page where you check contrast. Upon inspection I can see that your fallback background colour is exactly the same as your text colour: `#1B3664;`

You have to bear in mind that colour contrast checkers cannot work out the contrast on an image, so if you have an image background you need to check it manually.

Change your background colour on `.zHomeBanner` to `#fff` so that if the image fails you can still see the text.

### Banner Background Colour

```
.zHomeBanner {
    background-image: url(/Content/Images/USA-Learns-Homepage-No-Logo-E1Plus.jpg); <------background image
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-color: #1B3664; <------Fallback Background Colour, change to #fff
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #003466;
    font-size: .95em;
```

### Hyperlink Colour

```
a {
    color: #1b3664; <---link colour the same as your background colour on container
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

### Quick observations

The only thing I can see where you do have a slight contrast issue is your `Sign In` button where the contrast between the light blue and the white is only 4.03:1, so just darken that a bit. (also the bit that says 'advertisement' is same issue but I have AdBlocker so guessing that isn't an issue for most).

Oh and 'Teachers click here' needs bigger text, even if it is an image.

Comment: Thank you so very much for this detailed reply. I really appreciate the thoroughness, as well as your additional observations and suggestions.  Most excellent!  :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a default background color matching your image

That being said, you should not rely exclusively on automated testing. For instance, your drowpdown menu color on focus fails contrast  (#4f80bc / #fff)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  :)